# unlink() fails with "No such file or directory" right after existence was checked

Tags: c++, linux, file, filesystems

I observe pretty strange behavior in my application.

I have following functions:

```
bool File::Exists(const std::string & Path)
{
    struct stat S;
    if(stat(Path.c_str(), &S) != 0)
        return false;

    if(!S_ISREG(S.st_mode))
        return false;

    return true;
}

void File::Remove(const std::string & Path)
{
    if(unlink(Path.c_str()) != 0)
        throw Exceptions::Exception(EXCEPTION_PARAMS, errno);
}
```

The code i use is:

```
...
const std::string Path = ...;
if(File::Exists(Path))
    File::Remove(Path);
...
```

And at this point exception is thrown:

```
No such file or directory (2)
```

Key facts:

- Happens once every 1k-10k calls
- All files being removed are binary files, about 20MB
- This is called in application thread, however this is the only thread accessing those files (no other threads / process access them). Even no other process / user access partition they are located on.
- File being removed is located on mounted CIFS (SMB) (Network) mount point

Why does stat() report file being present, but unlink() sometimes fails?

Answer (score 2):

*Why does stat() report file being present, but unlink() sometimes fails?*

Because the calls don't happen at the same time.

This bug is so common it has its own [name and even a Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_of_check_to_time_of_use):

> In software development, time of check to time of use (TOCTTOU or
>   TOCTOU, pronounced "TOCK too") is a class of software bug caused by
>   changes in a system between the checking of a condition (such as a
>   security credential) and the use of the results of that check. This is
>   one example of a race condition.

Comment: This is not the case. There is no race condition because only one entity has access to storage.

Comment: @peku33 *only one entity has access to storage*  Evidently not. **This bug has a name and a Wikipedia page.**  And checking for file existence before deletion *is* a race condition that's not only useless, it's incomplete.  So what if if merely exists. Is it a read-only file system? Does the process have permissions to delete?  Unless you recreate all the checks done *that you don't have the data to do since you don't have access inside the kernel*, it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

How intensively are these calls being made? Are you trying to delete thousands of files at a time? Or one or two a second/minute? Over a network you could get all sorts of timeouts that could be interpreted as "No such file or directory", but in actuality is another problem.

And if you're about to delete them anyway, why bother checking for their existence at all? Just delete them, and check the exception to find out if it didn't exist, or whether there was a different error - or not even do that. Either they're gone, or you can't delete them anyway...

Comment: One cleanup() round called every minute deletes 10 files. Computer and storage are on 1Gbps lan network. This program is the only user of storage device. If I get "No such file..." - is the file actually deleted or not?

Comment: "Is the file actually deleted or not?" Usually, yes. But if the file is hidden from you, as far as you're concerned it's not there - even though it might still be. It all depends on your permissions.